# Trying to debug mixed datetimes and integers in passed array

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

I have two panda data frames `new_hpm` and `new_mr` with datetime index, and I am trying to subset one based on datetime index of another using `.loc`.

The datetime indexes on the two data frames are:

```
new_hpm.index
DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04',
               '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08',
               '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10',
               ...
               '2017-12-15', '2017-12-20', '2017-12-21', '2017-12-22',
               '2017-12-23', '2017-12-24', '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29',
               '2017-12-30', '2017-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', length=1093, freq=None)
new_mr.index
DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-07', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-13', '2013-01-13',
               '2013-01-13', '2013-01-13', '2013-01-14', '2013-01-14',
               '2013-01-14', '2013-01-14',
               ...
               '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31',
               '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31',
               '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date_conv', length=13366, freq=None)
```

However, when I do

```
subset_mr = new_mr.loc[new_hpm.index]
```

I get the error message:

```
ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the duplicates present in `new_mr`, as seen in GH issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29855).

You could remove the duplicates in the index of `new_mr` before slicing or, in general, you want to perform set operations, there are better ways that work well with indices, e.g.

```
subset_mr = new_mr.loc[new_mr.index.intersection(new_hpm.index).drop_duplicates()]
```